# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is hanging on Dell Vostro 3490 Laptops

Tags: 20.04, dell-vostro

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is hanging on Dell Vostro 3490 laptops. Can anyone help in this? Your inputs are deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some specifics... are you using a GUI, which kernel stack are you using?  (GA, HWE, an OEM stack? etc) and when does it hang (during some operation, after some event/operation, has always hung, or after some update/package was installed ec)

Comment: cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-1093-oem (buildd@lcy01-amd64-012) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #103-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 15 09:45:49 UTC 2020
Its hanging regularly.